# $(this) and this inside click-event

Tags: jquery, function, this

i have an own js-class and try to use jquery's $(this) and object-this in an click-event.

jquery's $(this) works fine, but the object-this is not defined.

http://jsfiddle.net/j33Fx/2/

```
var myclass = function(){

    this.myfunction = function(){
        alert('myfunction');
    }

    this.buttonclicked = function(){
        alert('buttonclicked');
    }

    this.writeout = function(){
        var buttoncode = '<button class="mybutton">click</button>';
        $('body').append(buttoncode);

        $('.mybutton').click(function(){
            alert('Button: '+$(this).attr('class'));
            this.buttonclicked(); 
        });

        this.myfunction();
    }

}


var x = new myclass();
x.writeout();
```

When i click the appended button, i get an alert with the classname of the Button, but my function "this.buttonclicked" seems not to be a function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`this` refers to element which invoked the event in the event handler. You can cache current object in some other variable. Which can be used latter.

use

```
this.writeout = function(){
    var buttoncode = '<button class="mybutton">click</button>';
    $('body').append(buttoncode);

    var _self = this; //cache current object

    $('.mybutton').click(function(){
        alert('Button: '+ $(this).attr('class')); //Here this refers to element which invoked the event.

        _self.buttonclicked(); //Use cached object
    });

    this.myfunction();
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/j33Fx/3/)

Comment: is there a way to solve this when the callback function passed to click() is a method of a larger otherClass object which uses "this" inside trying to refer to the otherClass?

Comment: @JoseOspina, I don't know your exact problem, However you can have a look at [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: Great it works! now I just have to refactor all my app! that's fun! thanks! (I mean, for real: I was doing some ugly stuff to overcome this... thanks)